# E(number of goals)

Tags: probability, expected-value

In a $90$ min game with $2$ teams, the chance of scoring a goal for each team is $0.05$.

What is the expected value for number of goals in the game in the last $20$ min?
Is it possible to solve this $Q$ with this limited info?

I'm familiar with the $E(X=x) = x\cdot P(X = x)$ formula, but I can't figure out how to use it.
What should I consider the $X$ and $x$ to be?

Comment: We can't really solve this without knowing what happens with chances of scoring a goal as time passes

Comment: Or what the time interval with the 0.05 probability is.